# Analisar Primeiras publicações

Tags: bug, edições-sugeridas, filas-de-análise

Observei que quando analiso uma publicação e faço alguma edição ela volta novamente para fila de `Primeiras publicações` (acho que somente quando a edição é aprovada), com isso, conta como duas análises.

Comment: Ah entendi, mas são análise diferentes. A primeira você avalia se o primeiro post está conforme as recomendações que o site pede pra se seguir(afinal, é comum quem é novo não saber como funciona por aqui). Mas como sua reputação é menor que 2000, a outra fila é de edições sugeridas. são situações diferentes.

Comment: Não, volta para `Primeiras publicações`, inclusive eu mesmo analisei pela segunda vez com as edições que eu fiz.

Comment: É bom você citar a publicação na pergunta, até pra facilitar a apuração, caso seja um bug.